# Configurable Product - Shows available in category view but Out of Stock in Product View and without Add to Cart button

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product, out-of-stock

4 simple products associated to config product.
-website selected
-all enabled
-all set to instock / avail
-config set to instock
--I've been trouble shooting but cannot seem to create In Stock Visibility under the config product view on the Frontend.

As the title indicates Config Prod shows as avail in category view but once in product view the 'add to cart' button disappears and the Availability shows 'out of stock.

Just need to create drop down options for product with variable features.
Simple task seems impossible at this point. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inventory tab in the products, is `Manage Stock` set to `Yes` or `No`? If the configurable is set to yes and QTY is 0, all associated products will show out of stock.

Best way to set these is up Configurable does not manage stock, then QTY isn't looked at for stock status:

[image: Configurable QTY]

Then set Simples up to manage stock and input QTY per SKU:

[image: Simple QTY]

Run a reindex after making these changes and it should fix your issue.

I'm using BL Custom Grid, so your `manage catalog` view might not look the same - but this is what mine looks like for this group of SKUs:

[image: Catalog View]

Comment: This is great - thank you. Added note: I have a 3rd party integration that required an additional step within Magento to show visibility of a configured item but notes above are correct and assisted in fixing the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear this worked for you. For future knowledge, what 3rd party integration did you have installed?

Comment: The 3rd party is Epicor - ECC. Within the Epicor configuration I needed to set 'Show add to cart button for bundle parts' to YES. Was set to NO by default.